# ComboBox fire event every time item is selected even if the item is selected twice at the same time

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

**I need to fire an event every time I click on item in [ComboBox](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-method-clearValue) ,even if the item is selected**
**I tried to use some events like [change](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-event-change) :but its fire event every time I select new item,but it's not work when i click on the same item twice.**
**And tried [focus](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-event-focus): but it's fire just once when i focus on whole ComboBox I see in [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox) the events but i don't find any thing or maybe i misunderstand 



 This is the list of events:**


[image]

Comment: did you manage to get to the bottom of this?  I'm running into the same thing

Comment: unfortunately not yet ,i'm working on other parts of my project but when i need to come back to this point maybe i have to search deeper about this problem .

Comment: check my answer maybe help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do a custom code that did what I need

```
 listeners: {
        change: function (eOpts, newValue, oldValue, sd) {

            if (newValue == null || newValue == "") {

                var _record = this.findRecordByValue(oldValue);
                this.setRawValue(_record.data.title);

                return;
            }

            var record = this.findRecordByValue(newValue);

            var selectedIsbn = record.data.isbn;
            var selectedTitle = record.data.title;
            var selectedDataAuthor = record.data.author;

           //.....
           //.....

            this.reset();

        }
```

In this code every select fire event twice one when select and the second time when use `this.reset();` and in second time the `newValue`  parameter become null so I just show the previous value in combobox text by using `oldValue` parameter with no actual focusing .